# How to fix Error 504 (gateway timeout) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, stored-procedures

In my Laravel project, I have a page that include a process button. This button will run move data from a table to some other table.

This is my code of controller :

```
public function saveItem(Request $request)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        DB::unprepared("EXEC spUploadItem 'Proses', $this->kodeToko,'','','','','','',0,0,0,'',0,0,0,$this->idUserToko,0");
        DB::commit();
        return 'Done';
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        return 'Error'.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This code is inefficient, because when I upload 6000 rows of data, just 3000 rows that successfully move to goal table. Can somebody please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: use ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);